# setuptools does not distribute my data files

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have the following in [setup.py](https://github.com/vporton/xml-boiler/blob/48cee15/setup.py):

```
from setuptools import setup
# ...
setup(
    name='xml-boiler',
    version='0.0.1',
    url='https://github.com/vporton/xml-boiler',
    license='AGPLv3',
    author='Victor Porton',
    author_email='porton@narod.ru',
    description='Automatically transform between XML namespaces',

    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'': ['*.ttl', '*.xml']},
    scripts=['bin/boiler'],
    data_files = [
        ('/etc/xmlboiler', ['etc/config-cli.ttl'])
    ],
    test_suite="xmlboiler.tests",

    cmdclass={'build_py': MyBuild},
)
```

But after I run `python setup.py build`, the build directory does not contain any `*.xml` or `*.ttl` files.

What is my error?

I also want to distribute all files from `xmlboiler/core/data/assets/` and 
`xmlboiler/core/data/assets/`.

---

I don't understand how it works:

```
package_data={'': ['*/.xml', '*/.ttl', '*/.net', 'data/assets/*', 'data/scripts/*.xslt', 'xmlboiler/doc/*.html', 'xmlboiler/doc/*.css']},
```

included `xmlboiler/core/data/scripts/section.xslt` but not `xmlboiler/tests/core/data/xml/simple.xml`. Why?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package_data` is a mapping of package names to files or file globs. This means that

```
package_data = {'', ['*.xml', '*.ttl']}
```

will include every file ending with `.xml` or `.ttl` located in any package directory, for example `xmlboiler/file.xml`, `xmlboiler/core/file.ttl` etc. It will, however, not include file `xmlboiler/core/data/interpreters.ttl` because it is located in `data` which is not a package dir (not containing an `__init__.py` file). To include that, you should use the correct file path:

```
package_data = {'xmlboiler.core', ['data/interpreters.ttl']}
```

To include every `.ttl` file under `xmlboiler/core/data`:

```
package_data = {'xmlboiler.core', ['data/*.ttl', 'data/**/*.ttl']}
```

This will include every `.ttl` file in `data` directory (glob `data/*.ttl`) and every `.ttl` file in every subdirectory of `data` (glob `data/**/*.ttl`).

To include every `.ttl` and `.xml` file in every package:

```
package_data = {'', ['*.xml', '**/*.xml', '*.ttl', '**/*.ttl']}
```

> I also want to distribute all files from `xmlboiler/core/data/assets/`

Same approach for `data/assets`, but omit the file extension in globs:

```
package_data={
    'xmlboiler.core': ['data/assets/*', 'data/assets/**/*'],
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how it works:
~~~
    package_data={'': ['**/*.xml', '**/*.ttl', '**/*.net', 'data/assets/*', 'data/scripts/*.xslt',
                       'xmlboiler/doc/*.html', 'xmlboiler/doc/*.css']},
~~~
included xmlboiler/core/data/scripts/section.xslt` but not `xmlboiler/tests/core/data/xml/simple.xml`. Why?!

Comment: To be included via `package_data`, a file has to match one of the glob patterns. `section.xslt` matches `data/scripts/*.xslt` and is included. `simple.xml` does not match any of the patterns. Example patterns: `*.xml` (any xml file in current directory), `**/*.xml` (any xml file in any directory), `data/scripts/*.xml` (any xml file in `data/scripts`), `data/scripts/**/*.xml` (any xml file in any subdirectory of `data/scripts`).